# Switching between nginx configurations (profiles)?

Tags: nginx

Given the following nginx configuration...

```
upstream myupstream {
  server localhost:9000;
}

location ~ ^/.* {
  root /path/to/var ;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

  # proxy_pass http://myupstream;
  # proxy_redirect     off;
  ...
}
```

I want to flip between proxied (using a node server at port 9000) and served (at /path/to/var) easily without having to comment out each block. Is there any tool or native solution to switch between different nginx configurations? (A solution would require using `nginx -s reload`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this. Request `/anyurl/?test=1` for switch to proxy, `/anyurl/?test=0` for switch back to local disk.

```
root /path/to/var;
error_page 464 = @proxy;

location / {
    # check if test argument found in request
    if ($arg_test ~ ^\d+$) {
        # set cookie and redirect to same location
        add_header Set-Cookie "test=$arg_test";
        return 302 $uri;
    }
    if ($cookie_test = "1") {
        # cookie "test" found, redirect to named location via custom error code
        # it can be any unused http code same as in error_page directive
        return 464;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://myupstream;
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround. A neat workaround I could use for one-offs, but this solution requires modifying the url. I'm trying to find a way to switch the actual nginx configuration (requiring an nginx -s reload).

Comment: Hm... it's easy to solve with bash/bat scripts which will copy required part of config and restart nginx.